# How to enter this http POST request into Postman?

Tags: postman

Sorry for an ignorant question. I'd like to use Postman to sent a POST request given by a framework which suggests:

```
http POST
https://api.telemetry.confluent.cloud/v2/metrics/cloud/query \
aggregations:='[{"metric":"io.confluent.kafka.server/sent_bytes"}]' \
filter:='{"op":"AND","filters":[{"field":"resource.kafka.id","op":"EQ","value":"zzz-12345"},{"field":"metric.topic","op":"EQ","value":"demo-topic-1"}]}' \
granularity=PT1M \
intervals:='["2021-08-14T18:37:00-04:00/2021-08-14T19:37:00-04:00"]' \
limit=1000 \
Authorization:"Basic base64(<API_KEY>:<API_SECRET>)"
```

Reading quickly through Postman doc [Sending your first request](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/). I can't figure out what to input in the UI of the Postman' POST request to reproduce the above instructions.

I actually could get the result using `curl` b/c the framework also gives a `curl` command. The point here is to learn how to use Postman.

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: you can import curl to postman, then you don't need to build each part manually.

Comment: I could manage after a while to mimic the curl command into Postman using body raw, json format. But b/c the http POST was given as above, I'd like to try to use that syntax. The hope is to learn how to use Postman. The output is more friendly than `curl`. Normally I would learn throughly my tools of trade. But this HTTP testing is not my main job, just want to fast track the learning by asking the question here hoping that the answer would be something obvious I overlooked.